# using dynamic data from highcharts in a html table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, highcharts

I am using `highcharts` and `jquery` to create a dynamically updating graph. I'd like to pull in the peak value that is visible on the graph into a html table, but am not sure how I would do this and am looking for some help on this.

I've created a JSFiddle file at: http://jsfiddle.net/s9kmsygn/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to achieve your requirement by doing the following steps:

1. Give the `<td> Peak value </td>` an #id so you can change it using jQuery
2. Calculate the maximum value as you create your `data` object
3. Compare this `max` with each value that you add using `setTimeout`function If `max`is smaller than the value, assign this value to max and redraw the peak value using jQuery

**Please see working [JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/s9kmsygn/5/).**

I also changed the `setTimeout` to 100 rather than 1000 so you can see how to the values spike without waiting too long.

================

**EDIT:**

This is a **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s9kmsygn/6/)** showing the **peak for the latest 10 data points**.

Comment: This is nice. Can it just pull the max of the visible data?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. Can you please give more details? The `max` that I made is the `max` from everywhere which means from both initial and newly added data.

Comment: So at any given time the graph shows about 10 points. I want the max of those 10 points.

Comment: @user2242044 My chart is always showing 20 points at any time, but the example I made is now showing peak for latest 10 points. Please see my edited answer above. If you want it to show the peak for the visible points only (which are 20) change this line `dataForMax.splice(0,dataForMax.length-10);`. Instead of `-10` you need to say `-20`